# adding a Company tax id filter using gform_field_validation on gravity forms

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, if-statement, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to add a filter to make sure people signing up add a valid Company Tax id number in Europe. All EU tax numbers go e.g. DE12345678, so that the first 2 characters are letters and the rest are numbers. 
Q: How do i add an "if" statement for each character?
`add_filter('gform_field_validation_1_44', 'tax-id-check', 10 ,4);
function tax-id-check( $result, $value, $form, $field ) { if ....`

Comment: which variable is the tax field?

Comment: it is Field ID 44

Comment: Please see the answer below

Comment: So i think it would be $field-> . '.44'

Comment: Do `var_dump($form); exit();` and same for other 4 arguments. And see where you have the field value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so lets assume that the tax field is coming as `$form_tax_data`

Now, you need to get the first two characters of the string and then just simply check it! See the code snippet below:

`$tax_id = substr($form_tax_data, 0, 2); //returns first two characters of the tax id
if($tax_id == 'DE'){
// do what you want}else{
echo "Sorry, enter a valid tax it";}`